# Generic Abstract String Converter

Tags: c#, generics

I am trying to convert my Action and Func based converters to classes so that I can quickly swap them in and out with minimal fuss.

The class that will accept them obviously has to store the converter as a variable

```
private Converter converter;
```

The class definition I have so far is :

```
public abstract class Converter<T>
{
    public abstract bool Convert(string str, out T val);
}

public class StringToFooConverter : Converter<Foo>
{
    public override bool Convert(string str, out Foo val)
    {
        //do the parsing here
    }
}
```

However I obviously cannot create a variable of the abstract generic class Converter without passing a generic to the class that houses it, which I want to avoid.

Comment: What about implementing a non-generic interface that is implemented by your abstract class?

Comment: @HimBromBeere I read something along the lines of that but I'm having trouble thinking of a fitting interface that I could implement it without generics? Any ideas what the signature of the function would be inside said interface?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a non-generic interface and implement it in your abstract class

```
interface IConverter
{
    bool Convert(string str, out object val);
}

public abstract class Converter<T> : IConverter
{
    public abstract bool Convert(string str, out T val);
    bool IConverter.Convert(string str, out object val)
    {
        T result = default(T);
        var success = this.Convert(str, out result);
        val = result;
        return success;
    }
}

public class StringToFooConverter : Converter<Foo>
{
    public override bool Convert(string str, out Foo val)
    {
        //do the parsing here
    }
}
```

As you can see the interface-method simply calls the abstract (generic) one. Thus you can now write this:

```
object anyOutObject;
IConverter myConverter = new StringToFooConverter();
myConverter.Convert(myString, out anyObject);
```

However as you do not provide the generic type you have to cast `anyObject` to your actual `Foo`-type.

Comment: Awesome! I had implementations using object but I couldn't make the last step. Much appreciated.

Comment: Just saw your edit; what would you suggest in regards to passing the generic type if I wanted to avoid the conversion?

Comment: You can´t as the interface does not have any clue on the generic constraint. However I assumed this was exactly why you didn´t want to use `Converter<Foo> = new StringToFooConverter()`? You have to provide the `Foo`-type in any way if you want to call any member of `Foo` on the returned object. Thus either cast or use your current approach.

Comment: I thought as much, and you assumed correctly. It's basically the problem I am having with this implementation. I don't want the class using the converter to have to do its own casting or hold any of that information but I can't think of a way to avoid it. I think maybe I should just stick to using delegates for now.